# how to show that this is isomorphic to a certain quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A,B,C$ be normal subgroups of a group $G$. Suppose that in turn, $A$ is a normal subgroup of $B$.

How do I show that $B/(A(B \cap C))$ is isomorphic to a quotient group of $B/A$ ?

Comment: Hint: use part (5) of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Theorem_C_(groups)

Comment: This is an instance of the Third Isomorphism Theorem. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIG HINT

The comments are directing you to use the following Theorem.

*If $N$ and  $K$ are normal subgroups of G such that  $N\subseteq K\subseteq G$, then $G/K$ is isomorphic to the quotient group $(G/N)/(K/N)$ .*

All you need to do is to apply this to an appropriate choice of $N,K,G$.

Can you now see what this choice must be?